# Grid and Canvas or both?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a custom designing software base of two libraries. From one library I can get methods to draw shapes e.g. `rectangle` and `ellipse` (it uses `Canvas` class in C#) and in another one a `adorner` class is used. I need to use both object (customer controls to drag/drop) and also need to give user to draw those shapes at the same time.

In former, I can see  `<lib:TheCanvas x:Name="myCanvas" />` has been embedded into XAML.
In the later, all the `adorner` object are created and dropped inside a `<Grid></Grid>` area.

Is it possible to combine these two and implement one application base of these two libraries such that both `Adorner` object and shapes can be dropped and drawn on on page?

Please advise.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: You can use adorners on shapes in a Canvas.  You should be able to just use a Canvas to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it looks possible, you can create a wrapper for your shapes(both shapes and adorner); and extend the Canvas control to support drag & drop for the shapes wrapper objects.

Look at this article series having similar implementation -

WPF Diagram Designer - [Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4), [Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23871/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-3), [Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23265/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-2), [Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1)